# Convert list of raw-vectors in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, raw

I have a list of raw-vectors named "output". Something like that:

```
[1] 58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 03 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 05 55 54 46 2d 38 00 00 00 fe
[1] 58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 03 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 05 55 54 46 2d 38 00 01 03 19 00 00 04 02 00 00 00 01 00 04 00 09 00 00 00 04 6d 65 74 61 00 00 02 13 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 01 00
[1] ...
```

They have different lenghts and are from the type "raw".

I need a dataframe with one vector in each cell:

| ID | vectors |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 03 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 05 55 54 46 2d 38 00 00 00 fe |
| 2 | 58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 03 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 05 55 54 46 2d 38 00 01 03 19 00 00 04 02 00 00 00 01 00 04 00 09 00 00 00 04 6d 65 74 61 00 00 02 13 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 01 00 |

I have tried this:

```
as.data.frame(output) 
#Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 27, 3132, 4141, 4267, 3701, 3943, 5200

df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(output), nrow=length(output)))
#Warning message:
In matrix(unlist(output), nrow = length(output)) :
  data length [32954] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [14]
```

Is there a way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `I` when creating the data.frame.

```
output <- list(raw(2), raw(3))
DF <- data.frame(ID=1:2, vectors = I(output))

str(DF)
#'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ ID     : int  1 2
# $ vectors:List of 2
#  ..$ : raw  00 00
#  ..$ : raw  00 00 00
#  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"

DF
#DF
#  ID    vectors
#1  1     00, 00
#2  2 00, 00, 00
```

Comment: Oh thank you! Never saw that I() function before... But its works great!

Comment: When Im creating the dataframe on this way, I found a problem in the cells of vectors. It should contain something like: `58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 03 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 05 55 54 46 2d 38 00` but I have now: `as.raw(c(0x58, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00))`.

Comment: Which problem have you found?

Comment: The structure of the dataframe `str(DF)` is the same but if im open the dataframe with `DF` the cells in the vectors-column contain as.raw(c(0x58...)) instead of 58 0a 00...

Comment: You should get with `DF$vectors` the same what you will get with `output`.

Comment: Yeah with `DF$vectors` and with `output` its the same. But with `DF` im getting a table with `as.raw(c(0x58, 0x0a, 0x00...))` in the vector cells. Thats a problem because I want to create a database with this dataframe and im getting `Error: UNIQUE constraint failed` all the time.

Comment: When im write `class(output[[1]])` then the output is `[1] "raw"`. When im write `class(DF[1,2])` then the output is `"AsIs"`. Maybe there is another way to create the dataframe with type `raw`?

Comment: Maybe `attr(DF$vectors, "class") <- NULL` could help.

Answer (score 1):

This can be also done with `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
output <- list(raw(2), raw(3))
tibble(ID = 1:2, vectors = output)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     ID vectors  
  <int> <list>   
1     1 <raw [2]>
2     2 <raw [3]>
```